# Laravel Dusk: The correct localhost port for APP_URL on a remote server?

Tags: laravel-dusk

I am trying to install Dusk on Laravel at a **REMOTE** host and at some point I need to change the .env file like this

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Another tutorial suggested something like

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:9515
```

For a remote host, do I need to put "http://localhost:????" and if I need how do I find the port number? I not do I just leave it as "/"?

By the way, I have tested several options and non have worked so far so but I am not sure what causes it so I am trying to pint point the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `APP_URL` to the same URL you are using in the browser for your local development environment. This can be `http://localhost` but also a custom URL:

```
APP_URL=http://dusk.local
```

For [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#configuring-homestead) you can manage your sites within your `Homestead.yaml` file.

The `APP_URL` is somehow important as commands from the terminal require this information as pointed out in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131290/1815847).

The port `9515` is the default port number of the Selenium server URL as provided in `DuskTestCase.php`. There's no need to change it at the beginning as it should work *out of the box*.

By default, the [ports are forwarded](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#ports) to your Homestead environment.