# Laravel dusk changes the URL

Tags: phpunit, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I have installed dusk for Laravel and since the beginning all the tests have failed. Instead of viewing the page that I want they all return a 404 error.

In order to find out what URL the test is trying to go instead of the one that I want I set up a custom 404 page and put the following code in it:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Now the test return the URL that it tries to get and I found that it adds a "/session" to the end of the URL for example if I try to check:

`'http://localhost/', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()`

The test returns

`<p>The requested URL /session was not found on this server.</p>`

If I set the URL like this:

`'http://localhost/fortest', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()`

The test will return:

`<p>The requested URL /fortest/session was not found on this server.</p>`

I don't know if this has something with Laravel/dusk or PHPUnit or Selenium. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45306147/1815847) it is important to configure the `APP_URL` to match your local development environment.

`/sessions` is usually the default session file location when using the native session driver.

For the start create the remote web driver instance with the default Selenium server URL and port:

```
'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
```

Then run your first test located in `Browser/ExampleTest.php` and validate the current URL.

You can quickly dump the current URL like this:

```
public function testBasicExample() {

    $this->browse( function ( Browser $browser ) {
        $browser->visit( '/' );
        var_dump( $browser->driver->getCurrentURL() );
    } );

}
```