# Laravel hostname not updating for routes

Tags: laravel, nginx, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, reverse-proxy

When I head over to my public DNS and attempt to load an `Auth` route, it sends me to `http://localhost:8080/ExoscapeWebsite/public/login`. Inside of my `.env` file, I have altered the `APP_URL` to my public DNS:

```
APP_URL=http://exoscape.co.uk
```

I am using NGINX to load Laravel by `proxy_pass` since I couldn't get `try_files` working so I stuck with using Apache2. My NGINX configuration looks like this:

```
server {

    server_name exoscape.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ExoscapeWebsite/public/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # manag$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/privkey.pem; # man$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Any ideas on how I could change the hostname in Laravel so it continues with the correct domain?

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache `, perhaps it helps

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I did that already, also, of I navigate to my domain/login, i receive a 404 error @KaranSadana

Comment: can you show , how you give link.

Comment: https://exoscape.co.uk/login @KaranSadana

Comment: i guess your issue is mode rewrite. https://askubuntu.com/questions/541105/nginx-over-apache-with-laravel-give-rewrite-mod-problems follow this

Comment: yes, change the 'url' value in config/app.php `config/app.php`

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you wanting to access your laravel app on your local machine with `exoscape.co.uk` or a remote server?

Comment: Sorry, yes. My Domain is pointed towards my NGINX server, I’m using NGINX as a load balancer since my server has 2 web servers running. I want to access the local machine files for Laravel, I am using PHP7.0 but following the tutorial gives me errors thus I used proxy_pass to Apache but now this doesn’t let me load more URLS and points towards the proxy domain @RossWilson

Comment: Ok. Which tutorial(s) have you been following and what are the errors you're getting? Your question is currently quite broad so we'd need a way to narrow down the issues. Also, just an FYI, `APP_URL` doesn't have anything to do with normal HTTP requests (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129092/what-is-the-significance-of-application-url-in-laravel-5).