# Laravel wrong domain in reset password link

Tags: laravel, router

I'm getting a bad URL generated by sendResetLinkResponse controller in laravel 5.8 having the domain twice.

> https://api.domain.org/domain.org/password/reset/....

But it should be

> https://api.domain.org/password/reset/....

The APP_URL is set to

> APP_URL=domain.org

I use a custom config to be able to have as endpoint api.domain.org instead of www.domain.org/api

My configuration is:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes() {

 Route::domain('api.' .  env('APP_URL'))
   ->middleware('api')
   ->namespace($this->namespace)
   ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you set it to `https://api.domain.org` what url does it produce?

Comment: I got a 404 on endpoint so I can't check.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Oh.. I forgot I'm using a custom configuration to be able to use as endpoint: api.domain.org instead of www.domain.org/api   I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting up your subdomain to be more dynamic i.e.

```
Route::domain('api.{domain}')
    ->middleware(['api', function ($request, $next) {
        $request->route()->forgetParameter('domain');

        return $next($request);
    }])
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

The above basically allows for any domain name and then the middleware just removes it from your route params so that it doesn't mess with your route closures or controller methods.

You will also need to add the following to the boot method of your service provider:

```
Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.]+');
```

This way you can use the `APP_URL` to just be the domain for the site.

Comment: Thanks Ross!  This works! Now I use the full url in .ENV and everything is fine, also the password link! Wow! Thanks!   Can you explain to me the patch to the boot?

Comment: Sorry, Ross. I've done a strategic error: I separated the API l logic from the frontend having 2 different servers and domains: www for frontend and API for the backend. So the link to recover password should point to www domain ( I could create a redirect on API side but I prefer to have a clean workflow). Then the frontend will pass the token in background to the API to verify and update. How can update your patch to serve the www url in recover link? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Uncoke Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "patch to the boot"? The `APP_URL` is used when Laravel can't actually figure out what the domain is -- have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129092/what-is-the-significance-of-application-url-in-laravel-5. So if you don't have any jobs, email etc. that require the url to point to the `api` I would just have it point to the `www`. If you do, then you will have to override any of the built in notification yourself.

Comment: @Uncoke https://laravel.com/docs/master/passwords#password-customization and https://pineco.de/customizing-the-password-reset-email-in-laravel/ should point you in the right direction